# Chang the citation style alphabetic of biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Is there a citation style in `biblatex` like `alphabetic` but without the numbers representing the year?

I.e. a book from 'Bach' and 'Schulz' written in 1978 schould get the label [BS] and not [BS79].

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Baur, S and Schmid, A},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It should be possible to configure the `alphabetic` style to do it. But you would increase the chances of receiving a good answer if you provided a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) for us to know more precisely your settings and requirements.

Comment: Apparently, that is not the first time you receive this advice. Perhaps you could have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I added one, is that good as MWEB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the appearance from your label in the `alphabetic` styles with `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{key1,
  author = {Baur, S and Schmid, A},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}

@book{key2,
  author = {Baur, S and Schmid, A},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
    \labelelement{
        \field[final]{shorthand}
        \field{label}
        \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
        \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
    }
%   \labelelement{ % this is removed from the default LabelalphaTemplate
%       \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
%   }
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{#1}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

In your case, as you want to remove the year digits from it. I simply commented the part corresponding to in the the default `LabelalphaTemplate`.

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! If there Baur and Schmid have a second book which is in my libary, it would be [BSa] and [BSb]. How could this be changed to [BS1] and [BS2]?

Comment: I added a formatting directive to that effect.